# App icon in Android 10 sometimes is wrong

Tags: android, android-10.0

I recently updated my phone to Android 10.

I discovered, that there sometimes is problem for my app icon, cause instead of real one, there is showing default one. Usually it happens after app installation, when I am opening it, then minimising that and then viewing it from active apps view.

Is there something, that I need to add in **AndroidManifest.xml** or it is just some Android 10 bug? Cause everything is okay on other API versions!

[image]

Comment: This Seems an OS dependent issue . I have faces similar issue on Android 9 Earlier updates ..

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest there is two lines for set icons of your applications

(1) `android:icon` for simple icons

(2)  `android:roundIcon` it will set rounded icon

for same icon you have to set image in both fields as below

```
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo" // for best result set your applications rounded logo
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
  android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon_app"
```

Comment: Tnx. But issue still remains. Sometimes there is icon showing and sometimes not after install. Looks like OS bug.

Answer (score 1):

First goto resources folder copy paste your `ic_launcher` and`ic_launcher_round` in all 
those `mipmap` folder as per image size.

If you don't have `ic_launcher_round` then delete `ic_launcher_round` image from all `mipmap` folder and Remove this line `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` from manifest.

At last goto `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder which is in your resources folder
and `delete` this  `ic_launcher` ,`ic_launcher_round` both file from the folder.

Then run the app.

This worked for me.

Comment: Tnx. For me both android:icon and android:roundIcon was required, for it to start working

Answer (score 0):

```
> add your launcher icon again by using image asset it should work like this
```

[image]